Geodesics in the Schwarzschild Penrose diagrams
I drew the Penrose diagram for the Schwarzschild spacetime the coordinate transformation (actually a series of transformations):
$$ \widetilde{T} = \arctan(T+R) + \arctan(T-R)$$
$$\widetilde{R} = \arctan(T+R) - \arctan(T-R)$$
Here, $(R,T, \theta, \varphi)$ are the Kruskal coordinates. With these transformations, region $I$ in the Kruskal diagram maps onto the region:
$$-\widetilde{R} < \widetilde{T} < \pi-\widetilde{R} \bigwedge -\pi + \widetilde{R} < \widetilde{T} <\widetilde{R}.$$ Region $II$ or the black hole transforms into
$$ 0 < \widetilde{T} < \frac{\pi}{2} \bigwedge \widetilde{T} > \lvert \widetilde{R}\rvert.$$
Similarly, we can figure out the limits for region $III$ and the white hole region $IV$. My questions are:
Firstly, why do the null geodesics start on the line scri-minus and end up at scri-plus? The null geodesics in the Kruskal coordinate system are $T = \pm R +$ some constant. How do the endpoints of this line map on to $\widetilde{T}=\pi-\widetilde{R}$ and $\widetilde{T}=-\pi+\widetilde{R}$? Secondly, why don't the geodesics end in the singularity? If the null geodesics start on the line scri-minus and end up at scri-plus, doesn't that imply that no photons cross the event horizon at $r = \frac{2 G M}{c^{2}}$?


$T=\pm R+C$ represents $45^o$ lines on this diagram. Hence the null geodesics from the past null infinity cross the horizon while the null geodesics to the future null infinity cross the anti-horizon. Perhaps you should be asking why the null geodesics on this diagram cannot go from the past null infinity to the future null infinity. (Same as your “How do the endpoints of this line map on to…” - since they don’t.) In other words, why can’t light bypass the black hole? +1
